# Kotlin check if two lists are the same apart from one list having an additional element?

Tags: java, arrays, list, kotlin, array-difference

So I have list A and list B.
A is of size n and B is of size n + 1.
I need to know if all elements in A are the same as all elements in B.sublist(0, n - 1).

```
A: [5,7,2,9]  
B: [5,7,2,9,1]
true

A: [5,7,2,9]  
B: [5,7,2,9,9]
true

A: [7,5,2,9]  
B: [5,7,2,9,1]
false (order matters)
```

Is there any elegant ways to do this using library functions maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`List` has a [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method, so you can express your conditions directly:

```
(b.size() == a.size() + 1) && (b.subList(0, a.size()).equals(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

```
return B.take(A.size+1) == A
```

Comment: Does this limit to 1 extra element?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- you are correct it doesn't, I correct it.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `b` cannot be empty, you could write:

```
return a == b.dropLast(1)
```